# Reading .json file and parsing its data?

Tags: javascript, json, frontend

I have `some.json` file in the same directory as my front-end `JavaScript` file. What is the right way to read the `.json` file, so then I could just do this:

```
obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

XHR. If you are using jQuery, then just use:

```
$.getJSON('path/to/json', function(obj) {
});
```

And XHR:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "file.json", true); 
req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
};   // la fonction de prise en charge
req.send(null);
```